# Is there a way I can deploy the Svelte kit node app in a sub folder?

Tags: svelte, sveltekit

My main app is also a svelte kit node app running already in port 3000 (https://qa.testing.com). Now I wanted another app to be run on https://qa.testing.com/video in port 4000. This is my svelte.config.js file

```
import adapter from '@sveltejs/adapter-node';
import preprocess from 'svelte-preprocess';

/** @type {import('@sveltejs/kit').Config} */
const config = {
    // Consult https://github.com/sveltejs/svelte-preprocess
    // for more information about preprocessors
    preprocess: preprocess(),

    kit: {
        adapter: adapter(),
        paths: {
            assets: 'https://qa.testing.com/video',
            base: '/video'
        }
    }
};

export default config;
```

This is working fine in my localhost. When I deploy in our QA server, the home page loading with errors, and the assets are not loading in https://qa.testing.com/video. Following is the error
**https://qa.testing.com/video/_app/assets/pages/__layout.svelte-9742a0ca.css net::ERR_ABORTED 404**

Please guide me to fix this issue. What mistake I did?

Comment: There likely is an Apache or nginx reverse proxy serving your main app. You will need to declare a specific entry that handles `/video` and subroutes requests and forwards them to your secondary app instead of the main.

Comment: App loading fine, the issue is assets are not pointing properly. How do I configure that?